# m2e shows error in execution for jaxb2-maven-plugin schemagen goal

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, m2e, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am using maven and the jaxb2-maven-plugin version 2.2 to generate the xsd by calling the goal schemagen.

Everything works find both when I run maven from the command line or when I run it within eclipse using m2e. So far so good.

Unfortunately, in eclipse an error/exception in the pom file is shown:

```
Execution serviceConfigs-schemagen of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:schemagen failed. (org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:schemagen:serviceConfigs-schemagen:generate-resources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution serviceConfigs-schemagen of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:schemagen failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction$1.runInWorkspace(BuildAction.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.shared.environment.ToolExecutionEnvironment.restore(ToolExecutionEnvironment.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.schemageneration.AbstractXsdGeneratorMojo.performExecution(AbstractXsdGeneratorMojo.java:528)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractJaxbMojo.execute(AbstractJaxbMojo.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 33 more
```

If I perform a Maven --> Update Project the error disappears for a while, however as soon as i build the project it appears again.

Does somebody knows how to get rip or this error message?

Thanks in advance
Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was realted to a bug in that version of the plugin. Updating the plugin to version 2.4 has solved the issue for me.